# Identify a drive mounted as a folder using smartctl for Windows

Tags: windows-10, smartctl

I'm trying to spin down hard drives from the command line in Windows 10. If I have a drive represented by a drive letter, this is easy to achieve using SmartMonTools. I can enter:

`smartctl.exe -s standby,now d:`

In my desktop, all HDDs are mounted as folders under SSDs. I don't see a way, from smartctl's documentation, to identify these drives. Am I missing something, and is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is probably more than one way to skin this particular cat, but if you go into:

Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management

All of your drives will be listed as `Disk 0`, `Disk 1`, etc along with their drive letter or mount point.

`smartctl` allows you to reference drives by that physical disk number with the identifier `/dev/pdX` (where `X` is the disk number) instead of the drive letter (amongst other identifiers).

For example, if the disk corresponding to your desired mount point was `Disk 8`, the following command should work:

`smartctl.exe -s standby,now /dev/pd8`

But unfortunately I don't see that there's a way to reference the mount point directly from the command line by directory name, to answer your main question.

But if you wanted to script it, you can enumerate physical drives and letters/mount points and then parse that info to get the physical disk, then pass that to `smartctl`.  I haven't done it myself, but this seems like a good of a starting place as any:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327718/how-to-list-physical-disks